# AWS IoT Core: Can not use Mqtt to connect with Cognito identity

Tags: angular, mqtt, amazon-cognito, aws-iot

The application is made by angular.

First, the user should login with Cognito. So after the user login, application will get the CognitoUser data, like its id token, accessed key, and session token.

Then the application will start to connect to Iot Core and try to subscribe or publish data to the topic I want. But I always have a situation that Mqtt disconnect immediately.

The following is my connection code:

```
export class MqttService{
  private awsIot: any;
  private iotDevice: any;
  public sendMessageSubject = new Subject<any>();
  public receiveMessageSubject = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { 
    this.awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');
    AWS.config.region = 'us-east-2';

    this.authService.getUserPool.getCurrentUser().getSession(function(err, session) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      } else if(session.isValid()) {
        this.initMqtt(session.getIdToken().getJwtToken());
      }
    });
  }

  public sendMesssage(value: string): Observable<boolean> {
    const topic = 'topic/topic1';
    const res = this.iotDevice.publish(topic, JSON.stringify({'message': value}));

    this.sendMessageSubject.next(res);
  }

  private initMqtt(idToken: string) {
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
      IdentityPoolId: '<< IDENTITY-POOL-ID >>',
      Logins: {
          'cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/us-east-2_XXXXXXXXX': idToken
      }
    });

    (<AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials> AWS.config.credentials).refresh((error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log('success');
        const deviceOptions = {
          clientId: '<< CLIENT-ID >>',
          host: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-ats.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com',
          protocol: 'wss',
          port: 443,
          accessKeyId: AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId,
          secretKey: AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey,
          sessionToken: AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken,
          reconnectPeriod: 0
        }

        this.iotDevice = this.awsIot.device(deviceOptions);

        this.iotDevice.on('error', (err) => {
          console.log('MQTT Error');
        });
  
        this.iotDevice.on('connect', (result) => {
          /* It is always triggered here, then go to 'close' scope */
          console.log('MQTT connected');
          this.iotDevice.subscribe('topic/topic1');
        });
  
        this.iotDevice.on('reconnect', () => {
          console.log('MQTT reconnect');
        });
  
        this.iotDevice.on('close', () => {
          /* It is always triggered immediately after trigger 'connect' */
          this.iotDevice.end();
          console.log('MQTT Disconnected');
        });
  
        this.iotDevice.on('message', (sourceTopic: string, payload: any) => {
          console.log('Message Received from topic:' + sourceTopic);
          console.log('Message content:' + payload.toString());
          this.receiveMessageSubject.next(payload.toString());
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Before I run my code, I also run the below command:

`aws iot attach-principal-policy --policy-name "<< MY-IOT-POLICY >>" --principal "<< MY-COGNITO-IDENTITY-ID >>"`

And I also have attached the Iot policy to auth identity role.

I think the main problem is at `'cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/us-east-2_XXXXXXXXX': idToken`, but I'm not sure.

If someone knows it, please tell me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I modify the policy in Iot Core, and it works fine now.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Original:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Connect",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:client/<< CLIENT-ID >>"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:topic/topoc1/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Subscribe",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:topic/topic1/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Just to note, your newly defined policy is overly permissive, in contrast to least privilege principle of AWS